# how i get time picker value with difference of 6 hours by selected value from timepicker?

Tags: android

I am developing an app, here i created date and time picker function.Now i want to show the time with difference of 6 hours from selected value of time picker.

I am using following code to do this but it gives wrong result for the selecting the values between 00:00am to 06:00am .i.e if i am selected 3am then it shows the result -3. How Do i solve this?

```
//java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
EditText txtDate, txtTime;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
TextView tvpick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnDatePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btnTimePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_date);
    txtTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time);
    tvpick=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvpicktime);

    btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnDatePicker) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
    if (v == btnTimePicker) {

        // Get Current Time
       final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText((hourOfDay) + ":" + minute);

                        tvpick.setText((hourOfDay+(-6))+ ":" + minute);

    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Try My answer and let meknow if any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
if (v == btnTimePicker) {
 Timepick
 }
```

Timepick() function

```
 private void Timepick() {


        mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        System.out.print("mcurrentTime"+mcurrentTime.getTime());
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(demon.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour-6);



                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
                        new SimpleDateFormat("hh");


                try {

                    String datestring1= simpleDateFormat.format(mcurrentTime.getTime());
                    String datestring2= simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(datestring1);

                    Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(datestring2);
                    long difference = date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();


                    long diffSeconds = difference / 1000 % 60;
                    long diffMinutes = difference / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                    long diffHours = difference / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    int diffInDays = (int) ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));


                    editComment.setText(String.valueOf(diffHours)+":"+selectedMinute);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }







            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time

        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

      }
```

> **Result**

- if 12:23 result 6:23
- if 22:50 result 4:50
- if 10:24 result 4:24

You can manage am pm Also

Comment: wow! code works really nice.. but their is one issue regarding to Am and Pm.How can i solve this?

Comment: example, when i entered 2am then it shows 9am here i want result as 9pm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic in onTimeset

`hourofDay= hourofDay-6;
 if(hourofDay<0){
 hourofDay=24+hourofDay;  }`

then display it...

Comment: hourOfDay= hourOfDay-6;
                            if(hourOfDay>0){
                                hourOfDay=24+hourOfDay;
                                tvpick.setText(hourOfDay+ ":" + minute);

Comment: i used above code but it dosenot show proper result

Answer (score 0):

if you want exact date and time. you can convert selected time to milliseconds and add milliseconds to it (in your case 6 hours of millis) and convert it back to time.